# What is the best way to get the inserted ID in oracle using EF?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, sequence

I have a query like this

```
myEntity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("insert into mytable (id, name) values (mytable_SEQ.nextval,'John')")
```

mytable_SEQ is a sequence created to generate unique ID for mytable

What is the best way to get the inserted ID ?

Comment: I don't think this is related to EF. You could introduce **OUT** parameter and use Oracle SQL [`RETURNING`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm) clause

Comment: @IvanStoev yep that's an option as well. But also, you need to weigh the additional complexity introduced by using a stored procedure. Plus it's _more_ code you may need maintain and which is not in the layer of the C# application.

Comment: It doesn't need to be SP though. It could be anonymous PL/SQL block, e.g. something like `ExecuteSqlCommand("begin insert into .... returning id into p_Id; end;", outParameter);`

Comment: Can you write for me the whole query ? if it is possible please

Comment: @IvanStoev it has to be stated that I'm no Entity Framework wizard, but using magic strings instead of say LINQ or any other type-safe provider gives me a bad feeling in the gut.

Comment: @kayess Me too. But that was the OP question, and that's why I commented it's not really EF related. The EF way would be to use `DbSet.Add(entity)`, `SaveChanges` and get `entity.Id`.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yep, that's what I meant.

Comment: @MehdiSouregi I haven't used raw SQL for a long time, my comments are based on some memories. Also I have no Oracle environment to test. I'm sure you can read the documentation and figure it out.

Comment: @IvanStoev because ive read that "an anonymous PL/SQL block ... can't "return" anything. It can interact with the caller by means of bind variables" link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371408/how-to-return-rows-from-a-declare-begin-end-block-in-oracle?rq=1

Comment: Indeed. I believe what we call *parameter* can be used as *bind variable* (I just forgot that you have to prefix it with `:` inside the SQL). Anyway, since I can't provide exact concrete answer, I'm taking off. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as *best way*. There are a couple of ways to achieve what you want. Basically the first is to execute [`sequence.CURRVAL`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns002.htm) to get the current value of the sequence. You could also do a query using `MAX(id)` to get the maximum value of the ID column.

Note: both of these aren't safe if you have concurrency. Another thread may modify both the sequence or insert a new record to the table.

To reflect your comment, the only thing I'm aware of is to use pessimistic locking on the table while you insert the row and select the maximum ID in the very same transaction.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing about concurrency. There is no other reliable solution ?

Comment: in sql server you can add OUPUT INSERTED.ID and get ur ID, too shame there is no such thing in oracle. Without mentioning the complexity of adding a simple identity column.

Comment: Ill take your solution because my app will not have any concurrency since I have not too many clients for my app, and i have a way to check if it is the right record after insertion..

Comment: "in sql server you can add OUPUT INSERTED.ID and get ur ID, too shame there is no such thing in oracle. " There *is* such a thing in Oracle. It's the `returning id into` syntax but you didn't like that when @ivanstoev suggested it. So really not sure what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I know this absolutly not the proper way, this is how i did so far :

```
int nextid = myEntity.Database.SqlQuery<int>("select mytable_SEQ.nextval from dual").FirstOrDefault();
```

and then

```
myEntity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("insert into mytable (id, name) values ("+nextid+",'John')")
```

I know it can be done somehow in one query..